# <List>.size() throws Resource not found Excepton

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am creation an android app using parse as my backend.

When I query the users like this

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.whereMatches("username", name);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
if (e == null) {
     if (!objects.isEmpty()) { show.setText(objects.size());}
 else {show.setText("No Tuples");}
     for (ParseUser singleobject : objects) {
                    mail[i] = singleobject.get("email").toString();
                    uname[i] = singleobject.get("username").toString();
                    i++;
                    }
 } else {
    show.setText("NO Success");
 }}});
```

When I try to run this code I get the following error

```
Process: com.example.nirmal.sportsparse, PID: 10491
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:254)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3925)
        at com.example.nirmal.sportsparse.search_players$1.done(search_players.java:68)
        at com.example.nirmal.sportsparse.search_players$1.done(search_players.java:64)
        at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:115)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The errors point at the lines where I use the objects.size() and findInBackground call.

When I remove the objects.size() call the functions works correctly and retrieves all the required tuples.

What is the reason behind this???

Comment: `show.setText(objects.size());` line causing issue . use `show.setText(String.valueOf(objects.size()));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
show.setText(objects.size())
```

it should be

```
show.setText(String.valueOf(objects.size()));
```

Comment: Is `show.setText(String.valueof(objects.size()));` same as typecasting with a String. What is the difference???   @apmartin1991

Comment: String.valueof is literally converting objects.size to a string. Its very strange that EditTexts accept null values fine yet seem to be very unhappy when giving them an integer

Comment: I tried typecasting it to a char but it still showed the same error but it worked now.Thanks @apmartin1991 for the speedy reply